# ng-include is not showing html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have create a custom Popup.html page, which will appear over the current index.html page. So i have included Popup.html in index.html as below

> index.html

```
<body ng-app="GameInformation">
 <div id="completeGames" ng-controller="gameInfo">
    <div ng-controller="popupInfo">
      <div ng-model="popup">
        <div ng-include src="'popup.html'"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="Row" ng-repeat="info in gameDetails | filter:searchTxt" ng-click="openGame()">
   <div class="Cell">{{info.GameName}}</div>
 </div>
```

> App.js

```
var app = angular.module('GameInformation', []);
app.controller('gameInfo', function($scope, $http)
{
   $http.get("data/GameInfo.json").success(function(response){
        $scope.gameDetails = response;
   }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
   $scope.openGame = function()
   {
      $scope.$broadcast('GAME_INFO_BROADCAST', this.info);
   }
});

app.controller('popupInfo', function($scope)
{
    $scope.$on('GAME_INFO_BROADCAST', function(event, args) {
        console.log("Received ->" +args.GameName);
        $scope.gameInfoPopupVisible = true;
        $scope.gameDetail = args;
    })
});
```

> popup.hml

```
<body ng-app="GameInformation">
   <div id="popup_content">
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <b>Game Name: </b>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                {{gameDetail.GameName}}
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Popup.html page got the entire information from json, when i click the table row from index.html. So it is working fine. But popup.html is not showing in the index.html page when call openGame function. I am not able to get the solution for this, how to show this custom popup.html over index.html? when i saw the html page in firebug then i realize that popup.html is present in the page but height of this is 0px, width is fine. So how can i do this? Please help.

Here is my application link

http://plnkr.co/edit/hDzPMCfjfSxtVKD2xJz3?p=preview

Comment: First of all remove `body` from popup.html it's wrong

Comment: I did. But still same issue. I converted body tag to div

Comment: Please check http://plnkr.co/edit/hDzPMCfjfSxtVKD2xJz3?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong usage of directive ng-include. And you should remove body tag from popup.html.
Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/yEiwiHY7yGXqgmju7xbD?p=preview

You should use:

```
<div ng-include="'popup.html'"></div>
```

instead of

```
<div ng-include src="'popup.html'"></div>
```

**Update**
Try to use `$rootScope.$broadcast('GAME_INFO_BROADCAST', this.info);` in gameInfo controller. Remember to inject $rootScope into controller: `app.controller('gameInfo', function($scope, $http, $rootScope)`

Comment: @VarunJi Your plunker works fine! popup is included and game data in popup is up to date. Popup is not visible, because you didnt show it up. Look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/34dUaDrQTLxPX8mUAdHL
You should remove css display: none from #Popup and add ng-show="gameInfoPopupVisible" in Popup div.

Comment: Wow.. Ultimate :) Thanks for catching my error :) Thanks a ton for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 important issues I found.

1. You have not included bootstrap JS files.
2. You have explicitly set visibility of your popup to none.
   `display:none`
3. Not sure why are you nesting ng-app inside popup.html. It is not
   required as you already have set ng-app on `body` tag

Below is a plunker fixing some part of your code although not a complete solution.
http://plnkr.co/edit/TszS69PxKWFRAvlBCGD3?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for Help. But i am still fighting with the the model CSS to make it look proper in center.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong here, but you have a  tag in your `index.html` file. you also have a body tag in your `popup.html`.

Therefore, Angular is inserting the body tag inside the div, meaning you'll have a body inside a div which may stop it working. I dont know if it will make a differnce but this is the thing that stood out to me immediately.

try removing the body tags and just having the parent popup-content div.

Also, you typed `popup.hml` instead of `popup.html` in the question - i dont know if this is a typo, but if it isnt and your actual file is named popup.html then it will not register `popup.html` in your angular app because you've spelt the extension wrong.

Comment: Its showing same. I am getting width as 1340px of popup.html. but height is same 0px, after clicking.